# How can I get a value from the select box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I want to get the value of the selected option from the selected box by using JQuery but it ain't working.

I have tried a million ways to do it. Trying to get its text instead, tried to get the value from multiple ways. To know what is coming in my jquery variable.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
     //First thing I tried
     var category = $('#category').val();
     alert(Category);

     //Second thing I tried
     var category = $('#category').filter(":selected").val();
     alert(Category);

     //Third thing I tried
     var category = $('#category').find(":selected").text();
     alert(Category);

     //Fourth thing I tried
     var category = $('#category').find(":selected").val();
     alert(Category);

     //Fourth thing I tried
     var category = document.getElementById('category').value;
     alert(Category);

     //Now directly taking the value of selected option by id
     alert($("#category :selected").attr('value'));

     //These are the code snippets I tried at different times so don't 
     //think that I did this all a time which can obviously throw some 
     //exception.
});
```

```html
<select class="form-control" id="cateogry" name="category">
     <option value="0" disabled selected>Choose Project Category</option>
     <option value="active">Active Project</option>
     <option value="drafted">Drafted Project</option>
</select>
```

All the options I have given above and tried all of them one by one and put an alert to see what is it getting and the alert said undefined. What can I do?

Comment: The first way is correct, why do you think it doesn't work?

Comment: `alert(Category)` should be `alert(category)`. Variable names are case-sensitive.

Comment: your select lists id is cateogry. if you change it maybe it will work. change the id to category

Comment: You're setting the variable `category` but alerting `Category` Javascript is case-sensitive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Html code

```
<select class="form-control" id="cateogry" name="category">
     <option value="0" disabled selected>Choose Project Category</option>
     <option value="active">Active Project</option>
     <option value="drafted">Drafted Project</option>
</select>
```

jQuery code

```
  $('#cateogry').change(function (){

    let value=$(this).val();
    alert(value);

   });
```

Get for option selected

```
$( "#cateogry option:selected" ).val();
```

Comment: You didn't fix the typo in `id="cateogry"`. `Val` should be `val`.

Comment: Yeah I writed from phone

Comment: Please edit the question to explain the problems and how you're fixing them. And fix the ID typo.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to spell it correctly in both places, instead of copying the mistake in HTML to the JS?

Comment: It's really not worthwhile to post full answers for simple typos. Just post a comment and vote to close it.

Answer (score 0):

your alert have Category (with upper case in the first letter) and your variable are category (without upper case, can you confirm if is a wrong spelling? maybe you are showing a none existing variable and one of yours atempts are working

Comment: Don't post an answer for simple typos like this. We already pointed it out in comments.